# Trouble with Android Licensing Server

Tags: android, android-lvl

I've tried to use the new license service of Android and I am facing some troubles. My code in the main activity looks like this:

```
  mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();

  String deviceId = Secure.getString(MainTabActivity.this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
            MainTabActivity.this, new ServerManagedPolicy(MainTabActivity.this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
            BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY  
            );

        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
```

(basically just the shown code of the Android online documentation. The callback passes through if it's allowed and if it's not it displays a message and quits the app. So far so good.

The problem is that it works fine in the debugger, but when I publish it to the market and upgrade my app (I've purchased a version of my app with my personal gmail-accout, so I am a legitimate user) I get the error that the my app is not licensed. I've even added my personal gmail address to the whitelist in my market-profile and set the status to "LICENSED" but it still comes up with the error. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you obfuscating the code?  I encountered a couple of problems caused by the obfuscator messing things up.

Comment: While we're on the subject, is the licensing server suppose to reject the developer account when set to 'Respond Normally'? I haven't installed it in the wild. Your post above makes me a little cautious. Please update if you discover the answer.

Comment: Yes i have obfuscating the code. I will try without obfuscating and let you know. If you have any other suggestions let me know. I have two accounts: developer account for publishing my apps, private account with my private mail on my mobile. i bought the app with my private account so it should be registered

Comment: You should still aim to obfuscate the code, but it's worth turning it off for testing just to eliminate that as a possibility.  I documented the two issues I had with obfuscating the LVL here: http://blog.uncommons.org/2010/09/13/android-lvl-obfuscation-pitfalls/

Answer (score 0):

The callback from the licensing service sometimes doesn't happen for several seconds - worse if there is network lag.  It will generally cache the answer in the service after a successful attempt to help reduce that lag on later app starts.

You most likely need to move the logic for closing the app (or disabling features) to later in the UI experience.

I've also had a few false negatives for users that were corrected if they closed the app and tried again later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and added

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"></uses-permission>
```

to the manifest, did the trick for me!